# CSS - Clearfix not working when clearing div

Tags: html, css

```css
.frame {
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.pre-left,
.pre-right {
    height: 102px;
    width: 88px;
}

.pre-left {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZJJC.png');
}

.pre-right {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2OlY.png');
    margin-right: -88px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.pre-mid {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD1SO.png');
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 88px;
}

.after-left,
.after-right {
    height: 53px;
    width: 79px;
}

.after-left {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wml1g.png');
    margin: 19px 0px -40px -65px;
}

.after-right {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDDhD.png');
    margin: -34px -65px -40px 0;
}

.after-mid {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh00z.png');
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 53px;
    margin: 19px 0px -19px 14px;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.group:after {
    clear: both;
}

.group {
    zoom: 1;
    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
    z-index: 100;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: calc(100% - 42px);
    margin: 24px 0 24px 13px;
    padding: 30px 35px 0 35px;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXc4d.png") 0% 50%;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QczND.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="group frame">
    <div class="content">
        <p> du er boos </p>
        <p> du er boos </p>
        <p> du er boos </p>
        <p> du er boos </p>

        <div class="group after-group">
            <span class="left after-left"></span>
            <span class="after-mid"></span>
            <span class="right after-right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <span class="left pre-left"></span>
        <span class="pre-mid"></span>
        <span class="right pre-right"></span>
    </div>

</div>
clearfix
```

I am having some issues with clearfixing this page.

http://haxholm.me/test2.html

I finally got everything looking like I wanted to, but for some reason I cannot clearfix the elemtent! I have no idea what is wrong and I have tried searching for loads of different solutions - none working in my case.

So what is my issue here? I need another set of eyes on this problem.

Comment: add browser detail please. it seems good for me

Comment: I am using Chrome. Also tested with Edge. same results

Comment: Never ever use negative margins or paddings.

Comment: Why not ? Negative margins are great!

Comment: what you are trying for clearfix? just writing clearfix keyword?

Answer (score 1):

> CSS - Clearfix not working when clearing div

Hi,

Some minor changes and your code will run perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <style>
        .frame {
width:1000px;
position:relative;
}

.left {
float:left;
}

.right {
float:right;
}

.pre-left, .pre-right {
height:102px;
width:88px;
}

.pre-left {
background-image:url('images/frames_01.png');
}

.pre-right {
background-image:url('images/frames_04.png');
margin-right:-88px;
margin-top: -30px;
}

.pre-mid {
background-image:url('images/frames_02.png');
width:auto;
display:block;
height:30px;
margin-left: 88px;
}

.after-left, .after-right {
height:53px;
width:79px;
}

.after-left {
background-image:url('images/frames_10.png');
margin: 19px 0px -40px -65px;
}

.after-right {
background-image:url('images/frames_13.png');
margin:-34px -65px -40px 0;
}

.after-mid {
background-image:url('images/frames_11.png');
width:auto;
display:block;
height:53px;
margin:19px 0px -19px 14px;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
} 
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
  z-index:100;
}

.content {
position:absolute;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
width: calc(100% - 42px);
    margin: 24px 0 24px 13px;
    padding: 30px 35px 0 35px;
    border-left:17px solid transparent;
    border-right:17px solid transparent;
    border-image: url("images/frames_06.png") 0% 50%;
    background-image:url("images/framebg.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    color:#fff;
z-index:-1;
}
         .group.frame {
            position:relative;
         }
         .group.frame .content + .group {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
      <div class="group frame">
         <div class="content">
            <p> du er boos </p>
            <p> du er boos </p>
            <p> du er boos </p>
            <p> du er boos </p>
            <div class="group after-group">
               <span class="left after-left"></span>
               <span class="after-mid"></span>
               <span class="right after-right"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="group">
            <span class="left pre-left"></span>
            <span class="pre-mid"></span>
            <span class="right pre-right"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      clearfix
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your element `.content` has a position of absolute - This means the parent container (`.group`) has no idea of it's height.

So it is acting exactly as expected - I would suggest making `.content` relative and the element which holds the top borders a position of absolute.